# EF Core 3.1 how to automap in Many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have constructed a database model in .NET Core Entity framework with a DB first approach. I have several Many-to-many relationships in my database, and they are all represented with a joining table.

Like so:

```
public partial class Test1
{
    public Test1()
    {
        Test1_Test2= new HashSet<Test1_Test2>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    ..

    public virtual ICollection<Test1_Test2> Test1_Test2{ get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public partial class Test2
{
    public Test2()
    {
        Test1_Test2= new HashSet<Test1_Test2>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    ..

    public virtual ICollection<Test1_Test2> Test1_Test2{ get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public partial class Test1_Test2
{
    public int Test1Id{ get; set; }
    public int Test2Id{ get; set; }

    public virtual Test1 Test1{ get; set; }
    public virtual Test2 Test2{ get; set; }
}
```

EF have constructed a Fluent API that supports this structure, with foreign keys and composite primary key in the joining table.

When I am to add something into this relationship, it is sort of a tedious operation, where I have to do something along the lines of this, in order to correctly populate my joining table:

```
_context.Test1.Add(Test1);
_context.Test2.Add(Test2);
Test1_Test2.Test1 = Test1;
Test1_Test2.Test2 = Test2;
_context.Test1_Test2.Add(Test1_Test2);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

From the old EF in .NET Framework, I remember that it was sort of straight forward to do an automapper functionality which would make me able to only do the following:

```
Test1.Test2 = Test2; 
_context.Test1.Add(Test1);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

This is convenient as EF figures out how populate the joining table automatically. Also this is much more convenient when I have to make requests from these tables.

Therefore, how do I add an "automapper" functionality in .Net Core EF DB first - Is this even supported?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In EF Core 3 Many-to-Many is not supported.  This is from the old docs:

> **Many-to-many**
>
> Many-to-many relationships without an entity class to represent the
> join table are not yet supported. However, you can represent a
> many-to-many relationship by including an entity class for the join
> table and mapping two separate one-to-many relationships.

As a partial workaround you can add a [NotMapped](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute?view=netframework-4.8) property or a function that traverses the two relationships.  You just can't write queries involving a NotMapped property.

But they are there in EF Core 5: [Relationships - EF Core - Many-to-many](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many)

Comment: I also read that, and hoped there were some sort of workaround as you mentioned. What you are suggesting, is that something along the lines of whats suggested here? https://medium.com/@ti.ka/many-to-many-relationship-done-right-in-the-entity-framework-multi-clients-users-130ac185f667

Comment: Yep.  Just like that.

Comment: Thank you very much :-)

Comment: Incredibly, this fundamental ORM feature [has been in the works for 5 years](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/1368) and counting

Comment: It's on the roadmap for the next version, to ship with .NET 5: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/plan#many-to-many-navigation-properties-aka-skip-navigations  But is not planned to support .NET Framework.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft as i want to implement a many to many relationships too if i understood I have to create manually the intermediate table and join it with the other 2 classes.
So, Whenever i want to join an entity from class 2 with class 1 I have to go through the navigation property of class 1 and add it. e.g `class1.joinedtable.add(class2)`
So if that is correct I have the following question:
1) if i want to delete an entity of class 2 from DB do I have to delete first from the Joined table and then delete it or by deleting it is getting removed automatically from the joined table ?

Comment: You can delete the join entity or use a cascade delete behavior.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft the two links in your answer now go to the same page - at first I thought there was a way to configure nice/sensible looking collection navigational properties manually in EF Core 3, then I realised doc is referring to EF Core 5. Perhaps answer could be updated slightly to make it clear that collection of some relational class is required in EF Core 3?

Comment: The page at the first link no longer discusses EF 3.